# Python- How to check if a Twitch stream is online

Tags: python, json, web, twitch

I'm trying to check whether a twitch stream is online using python. This question has been asked here before however now I think the responses are out of date in relation to the twitch API. 
For example https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/syndicate just says that I did not specify a user ID.
{"error":"Bad Request","status":400,"message":"No client id specified"}

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the Twitch documentation, a client ID is required or a 400 is returned.

To get one go to [here](https://dev.twitch.tv/dashboard/apps/create) and register an application on the Twitch developer portal

After that, you can choose how you send the client-id, either through a request header called `Client-ID` or as a query parameter called `client_id`

For more information, you can find everything I've just summarised [here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/using-the-twitch-api)